# How to create simple div with transparent rest of site?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create simple div with transparent rest of site (This div will be show after click in link or other div)

Here exemple:

[image]

Comment: make use of opacity in CSS........opacity:0.4; check this link http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_image_transparency.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);` as background? [**Fiddle For Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/BU4cJ/1/)

```
div#transparent {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:2;
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
div#content {
width:300px;
height:300px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to do with jquery. How display div#content after click on link

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to use jQuery UI. With jQuery UI you can use the `dialog` widget along with the `modal` property to get the same effect.  jQuery UI also has a lot of other widgets that are pretty useful.

**jQuery UI**:
http://jqueryui.com/

You can also add different themes to jQuery UI or make custom themes to get that transparent background that you wanted by using the jQuery Themeroller

jQuery Themeroller: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Working example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jk4ru/

Answer (score 0):

### with jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/bbgwB/

```
$.fn.center = function () {
    this.css({
        'top': ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2,
        'left': ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2
    });
    return this;
};

$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('.message').center();
    }).resize();
});
```

### used css:

```
html, body {
   height:100%;
}
.overlay {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.message {
   width:120px;
   height:200px;
   background:yellow;
   position:absolute;
   z-index:2;
   left:0;
   top:0;
}
```